# NSIS doesn't abort install when uninstall is in onInit

Tags: nsis

I have an installer that makes it mandatory to uninstall the previous version before the new version can be installed.

However, when the initial question gets asked it does so.  But the uninstall dialogue doesn't.

```
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION \
  "${PRODUCT_NAME} is already installed. $\n$\nIf you have software older than 3.0,     please manually uninstall it with Windows before procedeing. $\n$\nClick `OK` to remove the \
  previous version or `Cancel` to cancel this upgrade." \
  IDOK uninst IDCANCEL giveup

; I am giving up
giveup:
Abort

;  Run the uninstaller
uninst:
 ClearErrors
 ExecWait '$R0 _?=$INSTDIR' ;Do not copy the uninstaller to a temp file
 IfErrors no_remove_uninstaller
 no_remove_uninstaller:
 install:
 ; ..... snip
```

Then here

```
Function un.onInit
   MessageBox MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNO|MB_DEFBUTTON2 "Are you sure you want to     completely remove $(^Name) and all of its components?" IDYES NoAbort
  Abort
  NoAbort:
FunctionEnd
```

So, when it is a standalone uninstall it seems to be fine, but when it is uninstalling at the beginning, if a user says No/Cancel, the installer will still go on when they say no.  I can't think of a reason as to why.  As an ill side-effect, the program files icon on start menu is orphaned and the uninst.exe is orphaned.  But if you run the uninstaller "manually" it seems to be fine.  I had no changed any of that logic other than trying to get this thing to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to quote the path in ExecWait and then check the exit code:

```
Function .onInit
StrCpy $R0 "c:\old install" ; TODO: Somehow find the old install (in the registry? InstallDirRegKey?) and put its path in $R0
IfFileExists "$R0\*.*" 0 noOldInstall
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "${PRODUCT_NAME} is already installed. blahblah..." IDOK uninstOld
    Abort
    uninstOld:
    ExecWait '"$R0\uninstaller.exe" _?=$R0' $R1
    ; Exit codes are documented in Appendix D in the help file.
    StrCmp $R1 0 noOldInstall ; Success? If so we are done...
    Abort ; Uninstaller was canceled or failed, we cannot continue
noOldInstall:
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I have this already defined:

    !define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out how to parse new lines on comments, but should I use the readregstr to get the path?

Comment: Hmm the registry itself has the default key which is the full path with the name of the executable but don't have a path key as other programs do in the list.  Can I not use instdir or something?

Comment: ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM \
  "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
  "UninstallString"
  StrCmp $R0 "" no_remove_uninstaller   ; i didn't copy and paste enough so i think i can work that with your logic

Comment: Okay, sorry, one more thing this time, I mean it!  ExecWait to the full path deletes the orphaned, skipping the _?=$R0 b/c that failed... but before the installer comes, i have a custom plugin display something, but it pops up while execwait is occuring.  this didnt happen prior to switching the calling method.  i dont get why.